# How to add more filter yet pager using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have the following ajax structure that allows me to display 10, 25, 50 and, 100 records

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination li a', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('data-target');
        ajaxLoad(url);
    });

    $('#amount_show').change(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ajaxLoad('pagination.php');
    });

    ajaxLoad('pagination.php');

    function ajaxLoad(url) {
        query_params = {
            amount_show: $('#amount_show').val()
        };
        
        $('.data-pagination').html('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: $.param(query_params),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.data-pagination').fadeOut('1000', function() { $(this).html(data) }).fadeIn('1000');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

According to what I selected from the following HTML structure, ajax, it brings me the results sent correctly.

```
<select id="amount_show" name="amount_show">
    <option value="10" selected>10</option>
    <option value="25" >25</option>
    <option value="50" >50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

But I still can't understand how I can add more filters to my pager, for example type of client, type of user or a search engine.

Or search filter by date, I want to add so many filters to my pagination, but for this I need a little push of how to proceed.

This is my PHP code, can you explain to me how I can add more filters to the pager.

```
<?php
    $strs = '';
    $pagination_page = 'pagination.php';
    $defaul_records = 10;

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'] ? : '';
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    if (isset($_GET['amount_show'])) {
        $records_by_page = $_GET['amount_show'];
    } else {
        $records_by_page = $defaul_records;
    }

    $localization_sql = ($page - 1) * $records_by_page;

    $stmtPD = $con->prepare("SELECT idCliente,
                                    nomCliente
                            FROM cliente
                            ORDER BY idCliente DESC LIMIT $localization_sql, $records_by_page");
    $stmtPD->execute();
    $stmtPD->store_result();

    if ($stmtPD->num_rows > 0):

        ob_start();

        $strs .= '<table id="data-table" class="table bootgrid-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>CLIENTE</th>
                            <th>ACCIÓN</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

        $stmtPD->bind_result(
            $idCliente,
            $nomCliente
        );
        while ($stmtPD->fetch()) {
            $strs .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$idCliente.'</td>
                        <td>'.$nomCliente.'</td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="view_data" id="'.$idCliente.'">Ver</span>
                            <span class="edit_data" id="'.$idCliente.'">Editar</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
        }
        $stmtPD->close();

        $strs .= '</tbody></table><div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination">';

        $stmtPD = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente");
        $stmtPD->execute();
        $stmtPD->store_result();

        $BD_records = $stmtPD->num_rows;
        $stmtPD->close();
        $con->close();

        $total_page = ceil($BD_records / $records_by_page);
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;

        if ($prev > 0) {
            $strs .= "<li><a data-target='" . $pagination_page . "?page=1'><i class='icon-angle-double-arrow'></i></a></li>";
            $strs .= "<li><a data-target='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$prev'><i class='icon-angle-left'></i></a></li>";
        }

        for ($i = 1;$i <= $total_page;$i++) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $strs .= "<li><a class='page-link active' >" . $page . "</a></li>";
            } else {
                $strs .= "<li><a class='page-link' data-target='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$i'>$i</a></li>";
            }
        }

        if ($page < $total_page) {
            $strs .= "<li><a class='page-link' data-target='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$next'><i class='icon-angle-right'></i></a></li>";
            $strs .= "<li><a class='page-link' data-target='" . $pagination_page . "?page=$total_page'><i class='icon-angle-double-right'></i></a></li>";
        }

        $strs .= '</ul></div>';

        echo $strs;
        
        else:
            $stmtPD->close();
            echo "no records..";
    endif;
?>
```

---

Example of my table data:

```
idCliente    nomCliente    typeCliente    dateCliente
    1          Google         VIP        2021-03-30 22:00:58.277400
    2      StackOverflow      PRIME      2021-03-30 21:00:58.277400
```

Comment: Why do you use prepared statement if you still inject PHP variables directly into SQL anyway? `$localization_sql, $records_by_page` needs to be parameterized

Comment: @Dharman And how should it be? since this variable tells the query the results to show in the LIMIT, after the information sent by ajax.

Comment: Use placeholders and then bind the parameters using `bind_param()`

Comment: @Dharman I'm going to investigate it as it is used, the truth is that I have only implemented it when it is used (where and) in the query

Comment: Let's see the generated SQL.

Comment: @RickJames I have added the simple structure of my data table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that `pagination.php` has code to connect to the database, construct a `SELECT` statement to fetch the desired rows, then deliver them back to the frontend?

I see `?page=<<number>>`, but nothing (yet) about page size, nor about filtering.

Suggest constructing this inside the JS and send it:

```
pagination.php?page=3&page_size=25&color=green&size=big
```

Then, inside the PHP, use `$_GET` to see which arguments were sent, and react to whatever parameters are passed (and `! empty()`).

Then construct the desired query, something like:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE color = 'green'
      AND size = 'big'
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 50, 25
```

Peform that; get the results; `json_encode()` them; and respond to the AJAX query.

Then, inside the JS, you need a callback to receive that result and present it to the user.

You might be better off with XHR instead of AJAX, since you don't really need the "Asynchronous" part of AJAX.

Comment: It is easy to test the code, this is the basic structure of HTML and jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/v4mhp17x/ You just need to connect any data table in my PHP code, the file must be called pagination.php or another name but remember to change it in the jQuery javascript code. And it will work without problems, so you can analyze more how it works.

Comment: @ You have given me an example of this: `pagination.php?page=3&page_size=25&color=green&size=big` but how do I send that information through the jQuery javascript code? that is to say, how together or combine the information to be sent.